# In ruby, is there a method you can call on an object to return that object?

Tags: ruby

I'm just curious about this really, so please don't ask me why i want to do it :).

```
foo = "Hello"
foo.self
  => "Hello"
```

Or, as a slightly more realistic example, consider this:

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,3,3,]
grouped = arr.group_by{|x| x}
 => {1 => [1, 1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3, 3, 3]}
grouped = arr.group_by(&:self)
 => {1 => [1, 1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3, 3, 3]}
```

"self" doesn't work in this context, but that's the sort of thing I'm after.  thanks!

Comment: `#itself` does work.

Comment: From ruby 2.2.0, so it does, thanks.

Comment: Or `#tap`, but you need to pass it a block

Comment: @fylooi: True, but it kind of defeats the point: the main motivation for `#itself` was specifying a noop callback concisely and legibly using `&:itself` (as an alternative to `{|x| x}`). `{|x| x.tap {}}` is the very opposite of "more concise and legible". :)

Comment: @Amadan Fully agreed :P

Comment: It's useful to know about `tap` anyway, thanks.